# End a regular expression pattern with a string

Tags: regex

all. I have spent some time now to learn regular expression, but eventually there is a problem I cannot solve properly.

Lets assume the following 'string' (html-extract):

```
"{'2018-05-02', '2018-01-05', r, '2018-07-01', '2017-07-02', '2016-07-31' random_text XYCCC Letters and 55565798 ]}"
```

My intention is, to extract all values from '2018-05-02' ... to (and excluding) random_text. I tried to achieve this through chosing the "anything but" structure to achieve this `[^a]` (not a):

```
\'[^random]*
```

The above does not do the job, because random is not a string, but a set of characters, hence the `'r'` in the string will split my extracted value.

If there is no `r` in the text before the word random_text, this would work fine:

```
\'[^r]*
```

Is there any way to include a specific string as the end of my sequence. e.g.

start: `\'`
repeated characters unlike string: `[^{my_string}]*`

Appreciate any insight :)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Maybe (negative) lookaheads will do the trick.

Comment: Can there be dates pre-2018-05-02 you need to exclude? Or are you interested in all valid patterns say: `yyyy-mm-dd`? And do you want to extract *"all values"* seperately in a collection or as a full match?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/1) working for you?

Comment: I am using python, however testing on regex101. @JvdV that is interesting, but the string may contain also other elements before the random text, so not only the dates.

Comment: @Toto this is exactly what I was looking for! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will do the job:

```
'.+'(?= random)
```

Just replace `random` with the string you want to exclude at the end.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/1)

Comment: Thats great, the solution allows exactly to set the "end of pattern" with a desired string (?=\sXYCC) would get me to the next one etc. Nice solution, thanks